# How to add a class extends JPanel, and display its own panel and button?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I put a `JPanel(jp1)` on the `JFrame(fr1)`, but where is `jp2` going?

I would like to display the `jp2` contains in `jp1` on `fr1`?

(the button "start!" and "DEBUGGING" should both displayed on the window)

How to do?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class F extends JFrame {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    F fr1 = new F();
    P jp1 = new P();
    jp1.add(new JButton("start!"));
    fr1.setSize(1024, 768);
    fr1.add(jp1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fr1.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class P extends JPanel{
    private JPanel jp2;
    private JButton b2;
    public P(){
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp2.setBackground(Color.green);
        b2 = new JButton("DEBUGGING.");
        jp2.add(b2);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but where is jp2 going?"* `jp2` is never added to another container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add `jp2` in `P` to anything

```
class P extends JPanel{
    private JPanel jp2;
    private JButton b2;
    public P(){
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp2.setBackground(Color.green);
        b2 = new JButton("DEBUGGING.");
        jp2.add(b2);
        //???
    }
}
```

Add `add(jp2);` as the last statement

Comment: thank you, it does. I forget to add it to the P itself. after add this.add(jp2), works.

Answer (score 4):

use `this.add` or just `add` inside your class p to add component to jpanel p[class p].your class p is itself a `jpanel` because it is extended by `jpanel`.so you need to add `jp2` to that panel .

and care about your `layout` of `panel[class p]` you can set layout by setLayout.... inside class p

```
class P extends JPanel{
    private JPanel jp2;
    private JButton b2;
    public P(){
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp2.setBackground(Color.green);
        b2 = new JButton("DEBUGGING.");
        jp2.add(b2);
        // setLayout.....use a appropriate layout if you need
        add(jp2);
    }
}
```